# Bootstrap Navigation Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my Javascript that is supposed to open the 2nd layer of my Navigation does not work and I dont know why it is not working. Am I overseeing something obvious? Its a bit warm in my office atm. :D

```
$('.submenu').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($(this).closest("ul .sub").hasClass("hide")) {
            $(this).closest("ul .sub").removeClass('hide');
            $(this).closest("ul sub").addClass('show');
          }
          else {
            $(this).closest("ul sub").addClass('hide');
            $(this).closest("ul sub").removeClass('show');
          }
  });
```

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <div class="centering">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="navlogo" alt="trlololol" src="gfx/Logo_Friedhof_Bildmarke-01.svg"></a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="nav-img"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="submenu dropdown-toggle"><a href="#">Next menu level<span class="nav-img"></span></a></li>
                    <ul class="sub hide">
                      <li><a href="#">Blablabla</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Blablubla</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Blablibla</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  <li><a href="#">One link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown32<span class="nav-img"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Next menu level<span class="nav-img"></span></a></li>
                    <ul class="sub hide">
                      <li><a href="#">Blablabla</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Blablubla</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Blablibla</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: try jsfiddle.net for your code..

Comment: You use e.preventDefault(). check the method you try to navigate. Is it triggered?

Comment: jQuery `closest()` traverse **UP** the DOM tree, are you sure you want that? I think you need to select the children, like this: `$("ul .sub", $(this))` instead of `$(this).closest("ul sub")`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, ofc thats not what I wanted to do. ;) @pumpkinzzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest your `ul` inside of your `li` like this:

```
              <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Next menu level<span class="nav-img"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub hide">
                  <li><a href="#">Blablabla</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blablubla</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blablibla</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('.submenu').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul.sub').toggleClass('hide')
 });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hubkefw7/